# how to share post description using fb meta og tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i want to share my post to facebook share using og meta. everything works fine except post's description

i tried to put 
`<meta property='og:description' content="<%= @post.description %>"></meta>` ,but i got an error undefined method description..

here's my codes,, please solve this thx u guys

in my application.html.erb

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
      <head>
        <title><%= yield(:page_title) %></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta property="fb:app_id" content="<%= 1234567890 %>"></meta>
        <meta property="og:url" content="<%= request.original_url %>"></meta>
        <meta property='og:description' content="#{@post.description}"></meta>
        <meta property="og:type" content="website"></meta>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700" %>
    </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

It mean's the controller that calls the layout does not provide a @post or that @post is nil.

I guess that is your layout file? In that case the post must be provided by all actions that use the application layout (in the standard case, that are all actions)

Make sure to load the post correctly:

```
   class MyController < ApplicationController
     def index
       @post = Post.find(params[:id])
     end
   end
```

Or make a condition inside your template:

```
   <% if @post %>
      <meta property='og:description' content="#{@post.description}"></meta>
   <% else %>
      <meta property='og:description' content="Some default description"></meta>
   <% end %>
```

Comment: i put def index
       @post = Post.find(params[:id])
     end on my post_controller but i got errror Couldn't find Post without an ID

Comment: This really depends on the system you are building. You want to Display the description of a post as ogmeta . What post? Where does it come from. Why does it is the og meta of all the pages in your website? If it is only for the post show action then wrap the og in an if like I've written. Otherwise you need to consult a guide / doc / intro about rails and controller / view first